# Express-session req.session in Websocket Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, session, websocket, socket.io

I try to exchange sessions between express and socket.io -

When I connect to the Websocket, I can set userData in the session and also get it again on another Websocket event!

Server.ts

```
const session =  require("express-session");
const sessionData = {
    name: COOKIE_NAME,
    secret:COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store
}
const expressSession = expressSession(sessionData);

const socketSession = require("express-socket.io-session");
const sharedsession = socketSession(expressSession, {
    autoSave:true
})

 const io = new Server(httpsServer,{
            cors: {
              origin: "https://localhost:3000",
              methods: ["GET", "POST"]
            }
          })
  io.use(sharedsession);
        io.on("connection", (socket: Socket) => {
            socket.on("message",userdata=>{
                var data = socket.handshake || socket.request;
                (data as any).session.userdata = userdata;
                (data as any).session.save();
                console.log("From Session:",(data as any).session.userdata)
            })
            socket.on("getUser",()=>{
                var data = socket.handshake || socket.request;
                console.log("Got it: ",(data as any).session.userdata)// good!
            })
});
```

But now... when I set a session in a express route like this:

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    req.session.user =  {_id: '', firstname:'Hide', lastname:'myPain',email:'Harold@hiden.com', hasPain: false, };
    res.send('You are now logged in! => isLoggedIn:' + JSON.stringify(req.session.user));
});
```

And now I want to access this req.session.user in my Websocket event:

```
    socket.on("getUser",()=>{
        var data = socket.handshake || socket.request;
        console.log("Got it: ",(data as any).session.user)  // undefined!
    })
```

the session.user which I set in express route on req.session.user is undefined.. why? Is it meant to work like this, or is it just for exchanging inbetween Websocket events?

Or do I just have to trigger the

```
            (data as any).session.user= newUserDataFromExpressReq;
            (data as any).session.save();
```

on my socketio when the user call my express endpoint for login? So its not really an automated exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, everything what was needed was to add ["withCredentials"](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/) option to the client. This is needed when you have your client and server running on different servers/ports.

```
// client-side
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io("https://api.example.com", {
  withCredentials: true,
  extraHeaders: {
    "my-custom-header": "abcd"
  }
});
```